# How to install Office365 on Server with Office Deployment Tool?

Tags: xml, azure, cmd, virtual-machine, office365

I'm setting up a new server, and want to install Office365 on it. It's an Azure VM, so I'm connected via RDP. During installation, an office window appears and give me the error code 0-1008 (0)

Due my research I read that I have to use the Office Deployment Tool (like this [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/overview-of-the-office-2016-deployment-tool))

I downloaded the files (see the first code block)

It was downloaded successfully. Then I tried to install Office using another xml-File (see the second code block) and get the error message above.

I searched for this issue already, but I just found some solutions for Code errors like [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_dep365/getting-an-error-0-1008-0-while-deploy-office-365/efaa9d38-291d-48db-8f45-26a6efd845c0?auth=1)

```
    <Configuration> 
      <Add SourcePath="C:\office"
           OfficeClientEdition="64" >
       <Product ID="O365ProPlusRetail" > 
         <Language ID="en-us" />      
       </Product> 
      </Add> 
    </Configuration>
```

.

```
    <Configuration>
      <Add SourcePath="C:\office"
           OfficeClientEdition="64"
           Channel="Broad" >
       <Product ID="O365ProPlusRetail">
         <Language ID="en-us" />
      </Add>
      <Updates Enabled="TRUE" />
       <Display Level="None" AcceptEULA="TRUE" />
       <Property Name="SharedComputerLicensing" Value="1" />
     </Configuration>
```

So, I want to install Office365 on an Azure VM with Windows Server 2016 and I'm connected via RDP (Because of this, I have to install Office this way), but until now, I was able to download the files for installation only.

Comment: You should be able to simply download office just as you would on any other PC or workstation. Have you tried on more than one VM? Maybe there is an issue with that specific machine

Comment: No, as my enquiries show, it's not possible on a vm  with several users. I tried it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run the same xml-file for download (setup.exe /download) and for installation (setup.exe /configure). That's how I installed Office successfully